# Script is not working on server side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

`Response.Write("<script>document.getElementById('ButtonId').click();</" + "script>");` is not functioning, while on javascript debugging it is working fine on all the browser.

Comment: You probably need to register the script with script manager

Comment: Did you make sure it was after the element "ButtonId" was rendered to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to register scripts on the page.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "MyScript", 
  "document.getElementById('ButtonId').click();", true);
```

Scripts added using `RegisterStartupScript` are appended at the end of the page so that you can access all controls.

Answer (score 3):

`Response.Write` will add the content at the beginning of the page, and executes first, by then the controls are not rendered completely.
You should use `RegisterStartupScript`, which places the script at the bottom of the page and the code can access the controls properly.